# Is it possible to restrict abstract class to only declare functions present in interface

Tags: typescript, oop, nestjs, abstract

My useCase is I have 2 **abstract Class**(subClassA & subClassB) and I want to restrict that if class A has some method(funcA) then Class B must also have(funcA) and vice versa.

```
interface A() {
public funcA()
}

abstract Class subClassA implements A{
  funcA(){
    print ("declared in interface and defined in subClassA")
  }

  funcB(){           // restrict to create this method as this method is not present in subClass B.
    print ("this function is not defined in interface.")
  }
}

abstract Class subClassB implements A{
  funcA(){
    print ("declared in interface and defined in subClassB")
  }

  funcC(){           // restrict to create this method as this method is not present in subClass A.
    print ("this function is not defined in interface.")
  }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript does not have abstract classes. Do you mean TypeScript?

Comment: Also, assuming this *is* TypeScript, could you please fix the [syntax errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAoCUyDeAoABwFcAjAG2AWRiJAQ0zwF8884SBnMKRMZAYTJwOHZB1KDhHVMmABbAmQhyI4UanzJqtelk1bkBKKD7oARABMICIVAgXZIR5FiIUcEA6sxQ9x2IkhEVQzRi0WPC0aOgAhPQMEhIB6JOQ7LmMEPjAAe2QEOzhIZDAAC2BRFTKch2ES8sqIaocK5BAcviMIDlU+UACSSRFkGIA6SIMjE2RzMtborOAcp1b2vm9fFpXwaHgkUdCJlgj2DN4BINFxQcuY2QUlFTU0fQWGfS0p8BnLa1s-fomXZuZAeLwQHwgAFOa5DDgxQ7hVhRHT8eKJRIpNLdbiUbJ5AoQIooOaNZqg0Sk5BVUo1WSiNaGdK9fywy5ocYJL6mMxUhZgJYrBkdZAbKFbZzA-aI5DHIA) in your question by [edit]ing it?

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved through interface.

At first, let me show an example with interface:

```
interface Foo{
    run(arg: any):void; //method
}

class MyFoo implements Task{
    run(arg: any): void {
        console.log(`running: ${this.name}, arg: ${arg}`);
    }
}
```

If you want to deduplicate methods in derived classes, then you can use abstract classes. It means that all derived classes will have methods from abstract class.

[As TypeScript documentation says:](https://typescriptlang.or)

> The role of abstract classes is to serve as a base class for
> subclasses which do implement all the abstract members. When a class
> doesn’t have any abstract members, it is said to be concrete.

And an example of abstract class:

```
abstract class PersonBase {
  abstract getName(): string;
 
  printName() {
    console.log("Hello, " + this.getName());
  }
}
```

And an example of derived class:

```
class EmployeeDerived extends PersonBase {
  getName() {
    return "world";
  }
}
 
const d = new EmployeeDerived();
d.printName();
```

### UPDATE:

> I want to restrict that if class A has some method(funcA) then Class B must also have(funcA) and vice versa.

You can use interface. What is interface? An interface is a structure that **acts like a contract in your application, or the syntax for classes to follow**.

It means that if you extend your class by interface, then the extendable **class should implement all methods of interface**.

So to satisfy your requirement of *that if class A has some method(funcA) then Class B must also have(funcA) and vice versa*, we need to create an interface like you did and extend all classes which should have all these methods.

JavaScript does not have interfaces, but TypeScript has interfaces. Let me show an example:

```
interface A
{
    // run(arg: any):void; //method
    funcA(): void
}

class Foo implements A
{
    // this method `funcA` should be implemented because `Foo` class inherits `A` interface
    funcA = () => {}
}

class Bar implements A
{
    // this method `funcA` should be implemented because `Foo` class inherits `A` interface
    funcA = () => {}
}
```

> restrict to create this method as this method is not present in
> subClass A.

There is no way to restrict creation of methods in class. In my view, it is not useful feature and if you use interface, then it would be such kind of restriction. I mean when you assign object to variable of type of interface, then this variable will show onky methods which is located in interface:

```
interface AInterface
{
    // run(arg: any):void; //method
    funcA(): void
}

class Foo implements AInterface
{
    // this method `funcA` should be implemented because `Foo` class inherits `A` interface
    funcA = () => {}
}

class Bar implements AInterface
{
    // this method `funcA` should be implemented because `Foo` class inherits `A` interface
    funcA = () => {}
}
```

and there is one available method called `funcA`:

[image]

Comment: Please go through the shared code in question. I want to restrict abstract class to only define implemented methods. It should not be allowed to create its own methods. Can you explain how are achieving this?

Comment: @AnmolMiddha please, see , my updated answer